# How to get Cell data when I click on button which is on viewForFooterInSection in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am new in swift and I am facing problem when I click on button which is in viewForFooterInSection

my code is like this

In viewForFooterInSection

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let footerview = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell
            
            let dictFeeStats = arrFinancialYears[section] as? [String:Any]
            footerview.lblTimeSheetFooterID.text = dictFeeStats?["staff_timesheet_id"] as? String            

            footerview.btnAccept.tag = section
            footerview.btnAccept.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnAcceptClick), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            return footerview
        }
```

On Button Click

```
 @objc func btnAcceptClick(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell: TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell = self.tblview.cellForRow(at: index) as! TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell
        let comment = cell.lblTimeSheetFooterID.text
        
        print("buttonPressed ! \(sender.tag)")
    }
```

How can I get TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell value in comment variable.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a closure in `TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell` that accepts a string. When button is tapped, call that closure with the textview's text.

```
var acceptButtonTapped: ((String?) -> ())?

@IBAction func btnAcceptClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    acceptButtonTapped?(txtview.text)
}
```

In your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection`, get the text from the callback.

```
footerview.acceptButtonTapped = { text in
    print(text)
}
```

Comment: Your code is not working when I return return footerview.contentView

Comment: Why do you return footerview.contentview?

Comment: because on textview done click Footer view got disappears

Comment: why does it disappear? anything else happening inside the button action and `viewForFooterInSection` method?

Answer (score 0):

usually the user interactions placed in the cell. And after tap, tapped cell informs the tablewView through callbacks.

**This a cell code:**

```
   class TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var btnAccept: UIButton!
    var lblTimeSheetFooterID: UITextView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        btnAccept = UIButton()
        btnAccept.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnAcceptClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    //Callback for communication between cell and tableView
    var btnDidTap: ((String) -> Void)?
    
    @objc func btnAcceptClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        btnDidTap?(lblTimeSheetFooterID.text ?? "")
    }
    
    

    
}
```

**This is a footer function in tableView delegate:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerview = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell
    
    let dictFeeStats = arrFinancialYears[section] as? [String: Any]
    
    footerview.btnDidTap = { comment in
        print("section number: \(section) DID TAP!")
    }
    
    return footerview
}
```

Comment: how can I get data of textview on button click?

Comment: I updated the answer. if lblTimeSheetFooterID is your UITextField or UILabel it should work for you

Comment: Not working this method is not getting called on button click
footerview.btnDidTap = { comment in
        print("section number: \(section) DID TAP!")
    }

Comment: Can you share your existed code? I think you forgot awakeFromNib function like in my example.

Comment: Also your  TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell  should be a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView . In another way, it shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use `footerView(forSection:)` method instead of `cellForRow(at:)`.

Replace:

```
let cell: TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell = self.tblview.cellForRow(at: index) as! TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell
```

With:

```
let footerView = tblview.footerView(forSection: sender.tag) as! TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell
```

Comment: showing me this error.  Incorrect argument label in call (have 'forSection:', expected 'at:')

Comment: I missed a bit. Try again, I've just updated the method.

Comment: Cast from 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to unrelated type 'TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell' always fails

Comment: Can you please check I have created .xib for TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell

Comment: `TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell` should be of type `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. It won't work otherwise. Make sure `class TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {`

Comment: Can't I convert it into cell?

Comment: It should have been possible. But `footView(forSection:)` creates an instance of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` while `TimeSheetFooterTableViewCell` is not inherited from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. You see why this won't work here right? Why don't you make a separate xib with the same layout, only difference being the the class would be inherited from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.